# Using XML-RPC Web Service in Android

Tags: android

Hello
I want to use "XML-RPC Web Service" in my application Android.
Help me.
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of doing some basic research with a search engine (I hear www.google.com is rather popular) before posting lazy "Help me" commands here.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/android-xmlrpc/

or

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml-rpc/xml_rpc_examples.htm